# strpos or pregmatch all in php vs MariaDB LIKE or IN query, which is fast?

Tags: php, mysql

Generally speaking, between using php built-in function and query statement, which method is the faster one?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Using strpos or preg_match_all to find certain string in Array or Object (maybe recursive function or loop will be needed) VS Just Using LIKE or IN to Mysql table.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example here?

Answer (score 1):

**DB like or in vs. strpos or preg_match**

You might have many rows in your database `table`. If you load them all and then do the filtering in app level using `strpos` or `preg_match`, that will mean that all records are loaded from the database `table` into memory, serve your PHP code, which in turn store those in memory. If the database server is different than the application server, then all the data has to be sent via a network or internet route. These memory operations and data transfers will slow down your operation, so it is much better to do the filtering at database side when you can, since even if for some reason db. operations are slightly slower than your PHP functions, large memory operations and data transmissions are just too much.

**like vs. in**

You can use the wildcard of `%` when you are doing a like. If you need that, then `in` will not be an option. Otherwise, when you are using something like this:

```
where myfield in ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

or you use this:

```
where myfield like 'a' or myfield like 'b' or myfield like 'c'
```

or you use this:

```
where myfield = 'a' or myfield = 'b' or myfield = 'c'
```

the first and the third options are equivalent, but you need to type less in the first case and you have an easier job generating your query. The second should be slower, since wildcards and stuff must be checked against.

**strpos vs. preg_match**

`strpos` finds the first occurrence of a needle in a haystack sequenctially, while `preg_match` searches based on a pattern. The latter is slower since it must check for regexp operators, but it has more possibilities, you can search for a pattern instead of a given needle string.